# jQuery Tabs in Shortcode API

Tags: shortcode, api

Pastebin of the html prototype and my attempt at the wp function -> http://pastebin.com/91zBv8sk

I want a simple notation so its easy for new users to use.  So something like this:

[tabs]

[tab title="tab title"]Content of the first tab[/tab]

[tab title="second tab title"]Content of the second tab[/tab]

[/tabs]

I understand why the function's notation is wrong but I figured I'd leave my best attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
function defaulttab( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $GLOBALS['tab_count'] = 0;
    do_shortcode($content)
    if( is_array( $GLOBALS['tabs'] ) ){
        $i = 1;
        foreach( $GLOBALS['tabs'] as $tab ){
            $tabs[] = '<li><a class="tab" href="#">'.$tab['title'].'</a></li>';
            $panes[] = '<div class="tab'.$i.'" class="tabcontent">' .$tab['content'].'</div>';
            $i++;
        }
        $return = '<div class="tabcontainer"><ul class="selector">'.implode( "\n", $tabs ).'</ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>'.implode( "\n", $panes ).'</div>';
    }
    return $return;
}


add_shortcode('tab', 'defaulttab');

function defaulttabs( $atts, $content = null ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'title' => '',
    'tab' => '1',
    ), $atts ) );

    $i = $GLOBALS['tab_count'];
    $GLOBALS['tabs'][$i] = array( 'title' => sprintf( $title, $GLOBALS['tab_count'] ), 'content' =>  $content );
    $GLOBALS['tab_count']++;
}

add_shortcode('tabs', 'defaulttabs');
```

Comment: Thanks, it works (or rather will work with some slight modifications).  I'm curious to understand how the function works, though (if you wouldn't mind explaining in brief detail).

Comment: Paste that in the functions.php?

Comment: @Helgi , yep in the functions.php would be fine.

Comment: Please igonre... spoke too soon